# How to parse emoji from Unicode charset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Running react application. I want to convert a Unicode string into emoji. But the problem is that charset related to browser convention.

For example:

```
Input

'&#128511 - nice emoji!'

Output
 - nice emoji!
```

Is there any convenient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

your string can be converted that way :

```
String.fromCodePoint(128511)
>>> ""
```

also your specific emoji has hex code `0x1F5FF`:

```
`${ String.fromCodePoint(0x1F5FF)} - nice emoji!`
>>>" - nice emoji!"
```

you can search for hex code in this [table](https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/emoji/emoji_v3.0/unicode_emoji_v3.0_characters_all.cfm)
you can yuse whatever you prefer.. just covert the number after th '&#' with `String.fromCodePoint()` ...